# Hook into rendering in Nuxt 3 with the new module system

Tags: nuxtjs3

I am playing around with nuxt3 modules, but I have problems achieving a few things.

Mode: SSG

Here are my requirements for my module:

- I need to hook in before a page will be rendered
- I want to add data that will be injected into the page and stored (like in  next.js when using getStaticProps)
- I want to share global objects in the `module.ts` and plugin files.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain the problem a bit more? I'm not sure if a module is the easiest approach.

In case you want to fetch data during SSG, you can use `useFetch`: https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch

Nuxt will fetch the data during page generation. The static HTML is generated, plus the API response is stored under `window.__NUXT__`. So on client side, the API call is not executed again.

Example see: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-oq1gxa?file=app.vue
If you open the example in a new tab, you see that no fetch request is executed. If you inspect the HTML itself, you see how the data is stored under `window.__NUXT__`.